# How can I test/debug a SSL/TLS connection using native Windows tools?

Tags: command-line, ssl, tls

I'm troubleshooting access to a remote global catalog server on TCP/3269 and I think something is interfering with the TLS negotiation between my host and the GC.

If this were a linux system, I'd typically use `openssl` -- something like: 
`openssl s_client -connect hostname:3269`.

I'm reluctant to install third-party software.  Is there a native command/tool in Windows to debug this type of connectivity? I know I can run a packet capture but I was hoping for something at the command-line.